# iOS How to monitor the clipboard content

Tags: ios

RT：how to monitor the clipboard content？

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(addword:) name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification object:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]];

[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"string" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

I try to use the notice and kvo way to find that can not be achieved

Comment: Where do you place this code? `self` is a `clipboard`?

Comment: self is a keyboard

Comment: in viewDidLoad , After my tests found that the notification is working in the app, but he is not working on the keyboard(appex) and I'm able to take the initiative to get the cut via [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] .string